# Confusion in konsole command in linux

Tags: shell, konsole

I was trying to open a new konsole terminal and source file after opening it. I tried the following command:

```
konsole -T hello --noclose -e "source file"
```

I wanted the terminal to remain open after sourcing the file but even with `--noclose` the new konsole closes. How can I keep the konsole remain open

Comment: Can you write more details? which distro? "source file" is a script? in my tests, apart of inexistent T option, the konsole remains open

Comment: I am running on RedHat and the problem is independent of the command I use in the  -e option. Even if I just use `cd` or `ls` command, the problem persists.

Comment: I think maybe a bug in RH... I tried in ubuntu and in arch linux and in both cases konsole remains open... can you try upgrade konsole?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want interactive session after running source file.

konsole uses system() or popen() calls to execute -e parameter.
source is a bash builtin so you can't just call it.

It is difficult to tell bash to launch commands and then start an interactive session. There is --init-file and --rc-file options but they will be used instead of your usual configuration files. It is may be inconvenient.

I think this shell script will work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source file
exec bash
```

Put it in the file "script.sh", make it executable and launch that way

```
# Edit script.sh
chmod +x script.sh
konsole -e ./script.sh
```

I guess you set some variables in your file.
It should be exported if it used in interactive session.

```
export VAR=value
```

Or if you do not need interactive session you can use this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source file
echo "Press enter to exit"
read
```

Well. There might be a bug in konsole too.
Probably we should report it.